# How did Avraham refer to his father the Rambam in writing?

Tags: jewish-books, rambam, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

What term did Avraham ben haRambam use when referring to his father in his writings? (Compare to R' Ya'akov ben Asher *(the Tur),* referring to his father *(the Rosh),* as Adoni Avi or A"A.) Did he use a similar term, or did he call him 'Rambam'?

Comment: Perhaps edit the question to 'R. Avraham" as he was a rabbi himself (of a large area including Egypt) who among other things authored authoritative responsa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He calls him אבא מרי (or מורי). Examples include a [letter of his](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=29154&pgnum=49) printed in Toldos Rabbeinu Avraham ben Ha-Rambam, and [numerous](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40223&pgnum=10) [places](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40223&pgnum=399) in his commentary on the Torah.

Comment: @Vram: it's probably indeed from the Aramaic מר, otherwise it would be אבי מורי (as in bentching). The phrase is often found in the Gemara (e.g., Berachos 29b and Kiddushin 31b), and mostly it's as part of sentences in Aramaic. As for your second question: R. Avraham's commentary was written in Judeo-Arabic (the examples I linked to each have the original on the facing page); the letter I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find a pdf online, but many of his responsa mention his father the same way. Consider the opening of responsa #2:

תשובה: פירוש אבא מארי זצ"ל...‏